# Single setup exe file Qt Application deployment

Tags: qt, deployment, msvc12

I want to deploy Qt application with different Windows system.
So I generated exe file for my application using windeployqt tools which consists of exe(Mingw) file with additional folder and dll file.

My requirement is how to generate exe(MSVC compiler based) file will deploy in different computer machines.

Thanks In advance

Comment: You create an installer which usually does always extract your files. If you want a single application without an installer you must build statically.

Comment: Why are you downloading NSIS from a 3rd-party website? Its home is on SourceForge.net

Comment: @user3606329 Can you please help me out how to build statically

Comment: You need to compile the Qt source-code statically. This usually takes 2-3 hours. Then you can link the new static qmake in your kit to build single .exes, but beware they are bigger in size, such as 10mb for an empty hello world app.

Comment: @user3606329  Can you please provide any resources,examples,steps to build statically. And the final generated static file will contains only .exe or still it will generate few for more additional files like dll,folder?

Comment: See ny previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982419/how-to-release-a-qt-c-application-on-linux-and-windows/49988989#49988989

Answer (score 0, accepted):

==>Static Compilation for Windows -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwX_urJJOf8

==>Static Compilation for Mac/Linux -

https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2018/02/17/build-qt-statically/